# Difference between boost::chrono::time_point<> and boost::chrono::steady_clock::time_point

Tags: c++, boost, types, time

What is the difference between `boost::chrono::steady_clock::time_point` and `boost::chrono::time_point<boost::chrono::steady_clock,Duration>`, and why can't they be converted between each other?

It seems extremely redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They can be converted between each other if their durations are the same. For example, the following would be fine:

```
boost::chrono::steady_clock::time_point tp1 = boost::chrono::steady_clock::now();
boost::chrono::time_point<boost::chrono::steady_clock, 
                              boost::chrono::nanoseconds>
tp2 = tp1;
```

You can also use [time_point_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/chrono/reference.html#chrono.reference.cpp0x.time_point_hpp.time_point_cast) to cast one time_point to another if their durations are different.

**Example**

```
boost::chrono::steady_clock::time_point tp1 = boost::chrono::steady_clock::now();
boost::chrono::time_point<boost::chrono::steady_clock,
                              boost::chrono::milliseconds> 
tp2 = boost::chrono::time_point_cast<boost::chrono::milliseconds>(tp1);
```

Also, I'm not sure why you think they are redundant. If you look at the [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/chrono/reference.html#chrono.reference.cpp0x.system_clocks_hpp.steady_clock), `steady_clock` has the following member:

```
typedef chrono::time_point<steady_clock> time_point;
```

So, `boost::chrono::steady_clock::time_point` is just a typedef for `boost::chrono::time_point<steady_clock>`.

Comment: Ohhh Okay that makes sense. Thanks for the time_point_cast! That'll come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

`std::chrono::time_point` (based on Boost) is a **template** that can be used to define a class that can, in turn, be used to define a point in time. `std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point` is an **instantiation** of that template (i.e., a class) that can be used to define a point in time. So they're two rather different things with the same name. Sigh.

Various **instantiations** of `std::chrono::time_point` can, as @JesseGood pointed out, be inter-converted with `time_point_cast`.